# How to Generate a PDF Report for Spring Web Flow Visited Pages

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-batch

So we have a requirement in our application. What we want to do is to understand where exactly does the user abandon the page flows while navigating the application. So for example, there are Screens A, B, C and D

1. The user navigates to A,B and C and then confuses due to the kind of information asked in Screen D and closes the screen.

We want to generate a report of such abandoned pages with some unique identifier for each page abandoned at the End of the day or on request basis like a menu option for seeing the report anytime needed so that we know which pages we need to fix or make more user friendly.

Do you guys know of any functionality available with SWF or Spring MVC or any other framework which integrates with SWF and provides the requirement that we have?

Thanks in Advance,
Yogendra

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`FlowExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/FlowExecutionListener.html) to track the abandoned sessions:

```
public class AbandonedSessionFlowExecutionListener extends FlowExecutionListenerAdapter {

    // will be called when a session times out or is otherwise terminated
    public void sessionEnded(RequestContext context, FlowSession session,
            String outcome, AttributeMap output) {

        recordAbandonedSession(outcome);  //outcome is the last seen view-state
    }

    private void recordAbandonedSession(String viewStateId) {
        //write it to a database or something
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register it with webflow:

```
<bean id="abandonedSessionFlowExecutionListener" class="com.my.package.AbandonedSessionFlowExecutionListener" />

<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="abandonedSessionFlowExecutionListener" />
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>
```

It should be simple to generate a report from that point.

Comment: So you mean I have to add this as the Listener to all the flows? Or is there something like global listener which is added to all the flows? Also, I just came across something called as Spring Instrumentation Framework which has many MBeans to inquire on the SWF usage. So something like when does the flow start, did the flow ended gracefully, how many of the flows failed while execution etc etc...  Do you think instead of generating report and adding a Class like you mentioned, we use the facility of Spring Instrumentation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Instrumentation, but it seems like overkill for your original question.

Adding a Listener like I described only has to be done once, and it applies globally to all flows.

Comment: I did try this out and I found out that the sessionEnded method only gets called when you get to the end of the logical flow like a <end-state>. Ideally I would want to know each state i.e <view-state> abondoned by the user. Also, sessionEnded does not get called when a session is timed out, I set the <session-timeout> element of web.xml to 2mins and It wont call the sessionEnded even if it passed 2mins of time. Any clues?

Comment: Sorry, I now see I misread the documentation. You're right that `sessionEnded` probably won't work for your scenario.

Alternatively, you could implement one of the methods like `stateEntering` and do your own session tracking.  That would be significantly more work, but still probably lighter than adding Spring Instrumentation.